# Adding pages to android-viewflow

Tags: android

I'm using android-viewflow (https://github.com/pakerfeldt/android-viewflow) in my app. I can't seem to figure out how to add/remove pages from code dynamically. Is this possible? Do I need to add (override?) such methods in my adapter?

I am aware of Jake Wharton's ViewPagerIndicator (https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator), which has this capability, but I have not yet been successful in implementing it.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.